# split night shift timings and split the working hours in 2 parts in mysql

Tags: mysql-workbench

I would like to split the shift timings. 
night shift timings (22:01:00(day1) - 06:00:00(day 2))
I have 2 columns start_date and end_Date, 
suppose a person started at 23:55:00 and finish 1:20:00 
again started at 1:30:00 and finish at 05:50:00 
like this there are multiple records.

example 1

May I know how to split the working hours in 2 parts 
day-1 - (23:55:00) - (23:59:59) (4/5mins) (between 23:55:00 - 1:20:00)
day-2 - (12:00:00) - (06:00:00) (rest of the working hours)

and  one more example(2)

a person started work at 9pm
shifts should be split like this
9pm - 10pm (afternoon)
10pm - 11.59pm (day 1)
12am - 6am (day 2)

I tried this for example 1

````
select
            start_dt as start_date,
            end_dt as end_date,
            ucase(rep) as assignee,
            timediff(end_dt,start_dt)  as total_time_spent,
            (case
                when 
                    CONVERT(start_dt,TIME) > convert('22:01:00',TIME) 
                    and convert(end_dt,TIME) <= CONVERT('11:59:59',TIME)
                then
                    timediff(end_dt,start_dt) 
            end ) as time_spent_day_1 ,
            (case
                when 
                    CONVERT(start_dt,TIME) > convert('12:00:00',TIME) 
                    -- and convert(end_dt,TIME) <= CONVERT('05:59:59',TIME)
                then
                    timediff(end_dt,start_dt) 
            end) as time_spent_day_2 

            from table_1
            WHERE CONVERT(start_dt,TIME) > convert('22:01:00',TIME) 
            and CONVERT(DATE_ADD(end_dt, INTERVAL 1 DAY),TIME) <= convert('05:59:59',TIME)
          and ucase(rep) like '%xyz%'  ```
````